# Can I move the records in MS Access data table without using remove and insert?

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am trying move data with a tree structure and its data bounded to a MS Access data base .
currently its has as a remove () that removes the data from the Access data base and then separate function ,that's adds the data to the records. I am just interested to find is there is a straight forward way to go about this?

Comment: please update the question with your remove and insert method codes

Answer (score 0):

Databinding is not directly supported in the .Net framework be it Windows Forms or ASP.Net. So to answer your question, there is no straightforward way other than coding it out.
This open source project could help you though: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7884/Data-Binding-TreeView-in-C

Comment: ok will check tht out. Ya i could see the start forward usage to share the code. Thank you for your suggestion